# How to draw pixel-by-pixel on bitmap in AvaloniaUI?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to write a drawing application that allows users to select two points on canvas and draws a line between those points pixel-by-pixel. In WinForms that would be an easy solution - create a canvas, get its bitmap, draw on the bitmap using the `SetPixel` method, and replace the canvas bitmap. I am wondering if there is a way to do this in a similar way in AvaloniaUI? From what I understood, it uses SkiaSharp under the hood. However, solutions to render `SKCanvas` on `Avalonia.Controls.Canvas` seem... hard. Although `SKBitmap` also has the `SetPixel` method. The question is not about how to draw a line - it is about how to **set single pixels on Bitmap in `AvaloniaUI` and set this bitmap to the `Avalonia.Controls.Canvas`**.
Here are some links I found:

- https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/2371
- https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/2492
- [AvaloniaUI - How to draw directly on the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805714/avaloniaui-how-to-draw-directly-on-the-canvas) - Unfortunately, I am not allowed to draw on the canvas itself.
- [Artifacts on Avalonia WriteableBitmap BitmapContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209683/artifacts-on-avalonia-writeablebitmap-bitmapcontext) - unsafe code, three extension methods... while an option seems a little bit too complex.

P.S. As tempting as this may sound, drawing a rectangle-by-rectangle of size 1x1 as in the official documentation example (https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/canvas) is also not allowed by the university.

P.P.S. I am not asking anyone to do the homework for me - in case you are worried about that please, consider this a framework comparison question, not a "please do that for me" one. I have found and linked solutions that I can use - it just seems to me that there should be a more easy way to achieve the result I seek. That's why I have asked the question - in case I missed something.

*Doing a Jedi thing: this is not some student trying to lay off his work on other people. You can go by your business*

Comment: @LeeTaylor - I am allowed to use the `SetPixel` method. Unfortunately, there is no such method on any of the native `AvaloniaUI` bitmaps. It is on the `SkBitmap` and `System.Drawing.Bitmap` - but converting between different bitmap types doesn't seem like a concise solution to me (the examples I have linked show how to achieve this, though). 

Regarding drawing lines: this is not a part of my question - everything you have described is actually a part of the task - Implement correct line drawing, anti-aliasing, and thickness modification algorithms using `SetPixel`. Those I know how to do 

Comment: @KirylVolkau Perhaps you can use writeableBitmap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209683/artifacts-on-avalonia-writeablebitmap-bitmapcontext

Comment: @LeeTaylor oh yes, thank you. This was also one of the solutions I looked at, forgot to reference it. This is the solution that uses `unsafe` code for pixel copying and requires three additional extension methods. This is indeed an option - still, I think the framework should have something that will just work, not requiring users to re-invent the wheel. I still hope that I've just missed something in the documentation or there is a guru who knows "the way". I will also add this reference to the original question and explain why this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Since you say you are arbitrarily limited to use a function named `SetPixel` or one setting a pixel one by one, this effectively seems to be a question about how to convert from an `SkBitmap` or `System.Drawing.Image` to an Avalonia image, as the latter doesn't provide such method. At the same time, you state you already found solutions for this, and seemingly have trouble using them - I recommend focusing on that by pointing out the code you found and have problems with, as the question is otherwise too unclear and impossible to answer.

Comment: @Ray I see your point in how the question is unclear - I think I have found the main answer: it doesn't seem possible to set pixels on Avalonia bitmaps, and the only solution is to actually convert between other bitmap types. Although I really don't like it. But! It does seem like a great opportunity to contribute to the open-source project. Thanks to everyone a lot (especially the moderator who cleared some of the controversial comments ), closing the question.

Comment: @KirylVolkau No problem. I think `writeableBitmap` would be a good direction to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: you can swap bitmap on the image control: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/image

The original question (although poorly stated, my bad) was intented to clarify if there is a way to perform the `SetPixel` operation on the Avalonia bitmap. Unfortunately, currently, it doesn't seem like an available option: so the only way is to either create a custom drawing context OR control OR conversion between different Bitmap types (like `System.Drawing.Bitmap` or `SkBitmap` from `SkiaSharp`) to `Avalonia.WriteableBitmap`. All those solutions are referenced in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SKBitmap and draw on it however you want, then convert to an Avalonia Bitmap with the following.

```cs
public Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap SKBitmapToAvaloniaBitmap(SKBitmap skBitmap)
{
    SKData data = skBitmap.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
    using (Stream stream = data.AsStream())
    {
        return new Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap(stream);
    }
}
```

The resulting bitmap can be displayed in an Image xaml component using binding. Note that I have used the PNG encoding format instead of BMP. I found that using `SKEncodedImageFormat.Bmp` resulted in `null` data returned. Something to do with the underlying native BMP codec not available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this trying to find a 'safe' way to do `SetPixel` but figured I'd show you my unsafe method (no skia involed).

Here's `SetPixel` (see comments for more info):

```
unsafe void SetPixel(ref Bitmap bmp, int x, int y, byte r, byte g, byte b, byte? a = default, int quality = 100) {
    // NOTE a (alpha) is optional if bitmap has alpha channel
    WriteableBitmap wbmp;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        bmp.Save(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        wbmp = WriteableBitmap.Decode(ms);
        using (var lockedBitmap = wbmp.Lock()) {
            // get pointer to beginning bitmap
            byte* bmpPtr = (byte*)lockedBitmap.Address;
            // set stride depending on alpha presence 
            int stride = a.HasValue ? 4 : 3;
            // find offset to beginning of pixel
            int offset = stride * (wbmp.PixelSize.Width * y + x);
            // set each channel of the pixel
            *(bmpPtr + offset + 0) = b;
            *(bmpPtr + offset + 1) = g;
            *(bmpPtr + offset + 2) = r;
            if (a.HasValue) {
                *(bmpPtr + offset + 3) = a.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    // convert writeable bitmap back to bitmap and update the reference
    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        wbmp.Save(outStream, quality);
        outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // you could also just return the new Bitmap instead of passing by ref
        bmp = new Bitmap(outStream);
    }
}
```

Using `SetPixel` to set a `Canvas`'s background to a `Bitmap`:

```
void SetCanvasBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    // initialize your bitmap somehow..
    Bitmap backgroundBitmap = new Bitmap(File.Open("<Path to some image>", FileMode.Open));

    // assuming its 100x100px black bitmap this will make a red dot in the middle
    SetPixel(ref backgroundBitmap, 50, 50, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    // map the bitmap across the Canvas background
    canvas.Background = new ImageBrush() {
        Source = backgroundBitmap,
        Stretch = Stretch.Fill
    };
}
```